# Keeping track of Join Cardinality in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, indexing

I'm trying to find a good solution to the following problem:

We have a table t_position with a unique index on position_id and a non-unique index on account_id. We have a lookup table t_accounttree which keeps track of relationships between accounts. There are only two columns which form a composite primary key: (parent_id, account_id). We cannot denormalize the parent_id into t_position because each account can have multiple parent ids (it can belong to different hierarchies).

A typical access path is as follows:

```
select p.* 
from t_position p
join t_accounttree tt on p.account_id = tt.account_id
where tt.parent_id = 1234;
```

Here is the problem: the optimizer's cardinality estimates are completely off because different parent_ids have vastly skewed numbers of corresponding rows in t_position. We can see this like so:

```
select tt.parent_id, count(*)
from t_position p
join t_accounttree tt on p.account_id = tt.account_id
group by tt.parent_id
order by count(*) desc

parent_id   count(*)
---------------------
1234            80307
2345            68994
3456            29134
4567            12491
6789             3021
8888              422
9999              245
```

etc. etc. Because the optimizer treats all these predicates the same, it often has a grossly mistaken idea about the cardinality of the result set (which is used in further joins and views etc.) I looked into creating a bitmap join index, but it apparently requires that the tracked column function as a primary key of the lookup table, so I don't even see the point of it (you could just denormalize the primary key into the other table and keep track of the column stats...) and most resources on the problem are about this rather trivial scenario.

Instead, I'm looking at a situation where a non-unique predicate on one table has vastly skewed selectivity when used as a filter on joining to another table. I want to be able to add stats to the data dictionaries that allow the optimizer to know selectivity of the parent_id predicate with respect to the t_position table as shown above. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you just need a histogram on the `parent_id` column on `t_accounttree`.  How are you gathering statistics, what version of Oracle are you using, and what are your default settings for the `dbms_stats` calls?

Comment: What I need is actually a histogram that tracks the intersection of parent_id in t_accounttree and account_id in t_position via the join column. Even if two parent_ids have X number of account_ids associated with them in t_accounttree (which is what that histogram would track), they could result in vastly different number of rows from the join, because the account_ids don't cover the same number of positions. The version is 11g R2.